# How to show the name of the logged user in the Page in ASP MVC without EF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a little ASP MVC Project without Entity Framework.

In order to show the name of the logged user in my page near Welcome (Example "Welcome John")I want to retrieve the values of  the attribute "Email" from the table "Client" and store it in a List "result" and then compare each Email of this List with X (which is the logged Email).

In case of equality, I retrieve the corresponding "LastName"  to this Email and store in a variable y.

In the End, I allocate y to the value of my Session. But I got always this error :

**ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized**

I am sorry for the quality of coding,please consider that I am beginner.

This what I tried :

in **Controller** :

```
  private void connection()
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DeliveryCon"].ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    }



    public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

    database_Access_layer.db dblayer = new database_Access_layer.db();


    [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Login(FormCollection fc, string LastName, string Email)
    {
        int res = dblayer.Admin_Login(fc["Email"], fc["Password"]);
        if (res == 1)
        {
            Session["currentUser"] = Email;
            string z = Email;
            connection();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Email from Client", con);

            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
            foreach (string x in result)
            {
                if (x == z)
                {

                    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("select LastName from Client WHERE Email= @x ", con);
                    //con.Open();
                    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter( "@x", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16);
                    param.Value = Session["currentUser"];
                    command2.Parameters.Add(param);
                    //con.Open();
                    string y = command2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    con.Close();
                    Session["currentUser"] = y;

                }
            } 
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Client");
            Session.RemoveAll();


        }
        else {

            TempData["msg"] = " Email or Password is wrong !";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }


    }
```

In **my View Create.cshtml :**

```
<h4>Welcome @if (Session["currentUser"] != null)
{ <h4> @Session["currentUser"].ToString()</h4>}</h4>
```

Comment: Open the connection in your `connection()` method. Add `con.Open()`

Comment: Which line gives you error? You are not opening connection before executing `comman.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: Also read about [How to make an ASP.NET site more secure, and how to implement authentication and authorization.](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security).

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya According to the Debugger, the error is in this line :

 using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
 {

Comment: @mshsayem I did it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have not called your Connection() function to initialize the connection and also you need to add conn.Open() to open the connection to the database.

Comment: Thanks ! The error is disappeared now but the name of user didn't appear in my page when I have logged

Comment: Try to debug and find at what point the email of the user is not set.

Comment: Can you clearly paste the exception details you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any Exception now I mean by NULL that the value of my query command "select Email from Client" is Null when I debug

Comment: the problem  I think now in this "where = x" in may sql query but I don't know how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a call to your private method connection
before you can use it in your execute reader.

```
if (res == 1)
{
    connection();
```

You are also not closing your connection with

```
con.Close();
```

You are better of doing it this way:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SQLConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DeliveryCon"].ToString())
{
    // other statements
    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("select LastName from Client WHERE Email= @x ", con);
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter(
    "@x", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16);
    param.Value = Session["currentUser"];
    command2.Parameters.Add(param);
    con.Open();
    string y = command2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    con.Close();
    Session["currentUser"] = y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! yes that what said also Ipsit Gaur above but I cannot now show the name of user

Comment: Place a debug point / watch at string y = command2.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); and see what y is populated with.

Comment: I tried but I got an error that the type or namespace SQLConnection could not be found

Comment: casing matters try SqlConnection

Comment: oh yes I didn' see it too sorry

Comment: that is because x in your sql statement is not understood. You need to use sql parameters to do that

Comment: ok you mean "where Email=x" I doubt also about this statement but can you please write me how can I make this comparaison

Comment: added above. What does your SQL clients table look like, what are the columns and datatypes?

Comment: thx again for trying to help, but I got now following your solution an exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in this line string (y = command2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();)

Comment: Can you amend your code above with your latest changes?

Comment: ok I will edit it and post it now but I didnt change the issue of connection coz when I did I got errors all over my code (others methods depends also of connection function)